# Customize Checkout for Specific Product Tags - Debut Theme

Tags: shopify, e-commerce, liquid, checkout

I am using the Debut theme. I have two types of products, one with the tag 'On sale' and others with the tag 'Normal'.

I want that if the customers add products with the tag 'On sale' the checkout is disabled. If they add products with the tag 'Normal', or products with both tags, the checkout should proceed as normal.

The following code helps to eliminate checkout for 'On sale' items,

```
{% if product.tags contains 'Normal' %}
  <Checkout>
{% else %}
  Not Available
{% endif %}
```

I tried to use operators (and, or) for including a scenario where checkout is possible with both tags but it isn't working.

```
{% if product.tags contains 'Normal' or 'On sale' %}
  <Checkout>
{% else %}
  Not Available
{% endif %}
```

The above won't stop checkout if there's only 'On sale' tag.

```
{% if product.tags contains 'Normal' and 'On sale' %}
  <Checkout>
{% else %}
  Not Available
{% endif %}
```

The above won't work because the tags are specific to one product and not both.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `{% if product.tags contains 'Normal' and product.tags contains 'On sale' %} ` need to update the code like this.

Comment: I tried these two codes when there were both products in the cart,
{% if product.tags contains 'Normal' and product.tags contains 'On sale' %}
<Checkout>
{% else %}
Not Available
{% endif %}

{% if product.tags contains 'Normal' or product.tags contains 'On sale' %}
<Checkout>
{% else %}
Not Available
{% endif %}

In both cases, the result is 'Not Available'. 

I also tried this when there is only 'Normal' or 'On Sale' products in the cart and it says 'Not Available',
{% if product.tags contains 'Normal' %}  
<Checkout>
{% else %}
Not Available
{% endif %}

Comment: in the cart, multiple products are added or a single product?

Comment: In the cart, there are two products; one product with 'normal' tag and the other with 'on sale' tag. If I use 'and' condition (suggested by you), the result is no checkout. If there is a single product (contains normal tag) or both tags, the checkout should activate. Else, if 'on sale' tag, checkout should be disabled.

Comment: You need to update the logic if there is more then one product.